# How best to traverse table rows, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
  <tr>
    <td><a class="payPlan">...</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="payPlanInfoRow">
    <td colspan="7" class="payPlanInfo">
           <div>...</div>
        </td>
   </tr>
```

When I click `.payPlan` I need to traverse to the DIV inside `.payPlanInfo`.

This issue is that this html structure will be repeated multiple times so I think I need to use `.find()` or `.closest()` somehow. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

I'm quite new to jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "closest" selector returns the first ancestor element matching its selector.

```
$(".payPlan").click(function(){

   var $relatedDiv = $(this).closest('tr').next().find(".payPlanInfo div:first");
   $relatedDiv.addClass('highlight'); //or whatever.

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this..

```
$(".payPlan").click(function(){
   var relatedDiv = $(this).parents("tr:first").next().find(".payPlanInfo div:first");
   //TODO: Stuff with relatedDiv
});
```

Where `relatedDiv` would then be the `div` in the next table row and you could do whatever you need to with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pv76W/

Comment: You need another parent() in there. `.payplan` is the link and not the TD

Comment: @JohnP yes you are correct, corrected my mistake, should've used jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td.payPlanInfo > div").each(function(i, obj){



});
```

Edit:

```
$("td.payPlanInfo").bind('click', function()
{
    $(this).children("div").each(function(i, obj)
    {
        // obj is your div, to what you like with it
    });

});
```

Comment: how do i implement the click function for a.payPlan ?

Comment: This doesn't answer his question at all. He needs to get the related div for each click of the link. You should edit your answer